# Calling external services with different source ip addresses from azure-aks pod

Tags: azure, istio, azure-aks, azure-load-balancer

We try to deploy our multi microservice application to aks for a big company. But, company infrastructure team asks us to request their services with certain private ip addresses. We have a vpn connection between company network and azure virtual network.

For example, we are calling company-service-1, company-service-2 and company-service-3 from one of our microservice, infra team says that, call company-service-1 with XXX.XXX.XXX.121 source ip, call company-service-2 with XXX.XXX.XXX.122 source ip and call company-service-3 with XXX.XXX.XXX.123 source ip. They had defined firewall rules for these ips and don't change them because of some security restrictions.

We could do that via defining different network interfaces to virtual machine and creating some ip routings like "ip route add XXX.XXX.XXX.YYY/32 via XXX.XXX.XXX.1 src XXX.XXX.XXX.123". But at that point, we are struggling with network interface addition limit. Because, at the end of the day, we are going to call 20 different services with different ips. Also, we might have more than one aks cluster, so this approach is not good.

And we try to that via egress load balancers like microsoft says. We try to add some loadbalancer via aks and it seems it get true ip addresses. But the problem is we can't define certain ip addresses for certain external endpoints. Every request from pods tries to go company web services directly without visiting load balancers and returning back from firewall with error.

[image: Load Balancers inside aks]

We created load balancers with yaml below. These are internal load balancers because, when we try to create public loadbalancer, we can't assign it certain ip addresses or maybe we miss something. We also tried it with public load balancer but no luck.

[image: Internal Load Balancer Yaml]

Also, We try to do that with Istio - egress features, we install istio with sidecar injection and labelled a namespace for test. We created virtualService, ServiceEntry, Gateway and DestionationRule but we can't find a way to give specific Load Balancer or specific ip for certain external hosts.

[image: ServiceEntry, Gateway, VirtualService, DestinationRule yaml]

We read a lot of documentations from azure and istio pages and searched a lot. We tried a lot of things that I can't write all of them here. I think, this should not be such an hard topic and there should be a valid way to do this. I am afraid we get lost. We don't have infra guy in our internal team and this is our first time working with Azure and azure-aks.

We are open to all ideas and thank you in advance for all of them.

Environment: we are using azure kubernetes services.
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"10", GitVersion:"v1.10.13", GitCommit:"954ff68d59e9dc62fa8252ffa9023a90ff8a358c", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-02-13T11:03:32Z", GoVersion:"go1.9.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}

Size of cluster: 1 node (test env)
General description of workloads in the cluster: an application includes multiple java-spring boot microservices

Comment: i dont think your problem is azure related. rather your customer is not exactly smart

Comment: @4c74356b41 öhöm öhöm :-) I don't exactly know why they want that but this is what they want and challenges us.

Comment: just whitelist vnet that is connected to vpn and thats it